# request post file failed

Tags: python, python-requests, http-post

I met a strange problem with requests, I print the file is not empty before requests, but the server response me the file is empty sometimes, also sometimes it's ok.

the client use python:

```
    if os.path.exists('files/%s' % file_name):
        files = {'file': ('result_%s' % file_name,
                          open('files/%s' % file_name, 'rb'))}
        logger.warning(f"文件大小：{len(files['file'][1].read())}")
        res = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

and the server using java only check following:

```
if (file==null) || file.getSize()==0:
     empty error
```

in this case will be a empty file error, so why this would happen, anyone met?

Answer (score 0):

I finally got a solution, hope helps:

try requests 2 times, with:

```
res = requests.post(url, files=files)
files.seek(0)
res = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

the second time will succeed, and the first try always fail.